# How to parse Multi-part form data in an Azure Function App with HTTP Trigger? (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, http, azure, multipartform-data, azure-functions

I want to write a NodeJS HTTP endpoint using Azure Functions.

This endpoint will be a POST endpoint which takes files and upload these to blob storage.

However, NodeJS multipart form data parsers are all in the form of httpserver or expressJS middleware.

Is there any available tools that can parse the multipart form data after it has all been received from the Function Application's wrapper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Azure Functions has wrapped http server object in Node.js, and exposes a simple `req` and `context` with several functionalities, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#exporting-a-function for details.

And mostly, Azure Functions is designed for triggers and webhooks requests, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs for the detailed comparison.

Meanwhile, you can try the answer of [Image upload to server in node.js without using express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745432/image-upload-to-server-in-node-js-without-using-express) to parse the request body content to file content, and upload to Azure Storage leveraging Azure Storage SDK for node.js, you can install custom node modules via KUDU console. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version--package-management for more info.

And I suggest you can try to leverage [Azure API App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app) in node.js to approach your requiremnet. As it is an expressjs based project, which will be more easier to handle upload files.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Seems like manual parsing is this only solution for now, though this may fail for large filesets.
I am aware of the API App solution, but it is good to get confirmation that multipart parsing is not part of Azure Function's intended use case (for now)
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To answer original question:

> However, NodeJS multipart form data parsers are all in the form of
> httpserver or expressJS middleware.
>
> Is there any available tools that can parse the multipart form data
> after it has all been received from the Function Application's
> wrapper?

Even 2 years later after you asked this question state of multipart form data parsers is not great, like you noticed majority of them assume `req` object which is a stream and tutorials/demos show how to parse multipart/form-data with express or httpServer.

However there is a `parse-multipart` npm package which can process `req.body` from azure function and return you array of objects with code similar to following:

```js
const multipart = require("parse-multipart");
 

module.exports = function (context, request) {  
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.'); 
    // encode body to base64 string
    const bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(request.body);
     
    const boundary = multipart.getBoundary(request.headers['content-type']);
    // parse the body
    const parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);
    context.res = { body : { name : parts[0].filename, type: parts[0].type, data: parts[0].data.length}}; 
    context.done();  
};
```

(original source: https://www.builtwithcloud.com/multipart-form-data-processing-via-httptrigger-using-nodejs-azure-functions/)

One area where I noticed `parse-multipart` can struggle is parsing forms with text fields. A slightly improved version which handles it better is called `multipart-formdata`:

```js
require('multipart-formdata').parse(req.body, boundary)
//returns [{field, name, data, filename, type}, ...] where data is buffer you can use to save files
```

Comment: This worked great for me with a form of multiple files. Can't speak to text fields though.

Answer (score 4):

I have good experiences with the new `azure-function-multipart` package. Example code might look like this:

```
const {
  default: parseMultipartFormData,
} = require("@anzp/azure-function-multipart");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  const { fields, files } = await parseMultipartFormData(req);
  console.log("fields", fields)
  console.log("files", files)
};
```

See [docs](https://github.com/anzharip/azure-function-multipart) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this adapter for functions and express, it may allow you to successfully use the multi-part middleware you want: https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express

As a less desirable option, you can parse the body yourself, all the multi-part data will be available in req.body and will look something like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymQMaH4AksAbC8HRW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

value
------WebKitFormBoundarymQMaH4AksAbC8HRW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""


------WebKitFormBoundarymQMaH4AksAbC8HRW--
```

I do think it's a good idea to support httpserver / express better in order to enable this extensibility.

Comment: It appears most of the node-based multi-part solutions (busboy, multer (based on busboy), multiparty, ...) expect `req` to be a stream (`req.pipe(busboy)` for example).  It doesn't appear the `req` provided by the azure function or wrapping it using `azure-function-express` supports this, although I could be overlooking something.  I'd love to be able to use the multer middleware with [multer-azure](https://github.com/winsome/multer-azure) and have it upload the files straight to azure blob storage.