# Uploading images via azure storage

Tags: javascript, function, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to upload images to blob storage via azure functions. Kind of struggling to get it working.

```
var data = new FormData();
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        data.append('file', file);
        data.append('name', file.name);

        xhr.open('POST', 'https://[blobstorage]/api/upload/foo', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data;');
        xhr.send(data);
```

The POST gets triggered in azure functions:

```
if (context.req.method === 'POST') {
        fs.readFile(context.req.rawBody, function (err, data) {
            context.log('data', data);
            blobService.createBlockBlobFromText(containerName, blob, data, {contentSettings: {contentType: 'image/png'}}, function(){
                context.done();
            });
        });
    }
```

This adds a file to blob storage but it isnt the image unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `context.log('data', data);` shows`undefined` in the logs. That's why you are getting zero size file. Unfortunately multipart parsing is not part of Azure Functions functionality. You can find more details here:
[How to parse Multi-part form data in an Azure Function App with HTTP Trigger? (NodeJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713479/how-to-parse-multi-part-form-data-in-an-azure-function-app-with-http-trigger-n)

Comment: cheers dude, been looking at it for a while, was hoping that I didnt have to create a node API but it looks like the only way.